# How to reattach google maps object to DOM?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, google-maps-api-3

I'm not sure the correct lingo for this, so feel free to edit the title of this post if necessary.

Basically, I'm creating a Google map object and adding a bunch of overlays, markers, etc. This is how I create the map:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions)
```

But then, navigating through the side, I may land on a url where the map DOM element is destroyed, but the map object still exists in my web app. When I go back to the url that displays the map, I'd like to reattach the map to the DOM element as opposed to recreating the map.

Any ideas how to do this?

EDIT:

To be more specific, I have a bunch of markers and overlays on the map

```
Map = 
  map: null
  markers:[]
  icons: {}


  init: ->
    mapOptions = 
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0500, -118.2500)
      zoom: 9

    @map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions)

    @icons.default = 
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE
      strokeColor: '#DD0000'
      fillColor: '#DD0000'
      fillOpacity: 0.6
      scale:8
      strokeWeight: 2

  addMarker: (post) ->
    gLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng post.location.lat, post.location.lng

    gMarker = new google.maps.Marker
      position: gLatLng
      map: @map
      icon: @icons.default
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP

    marker =
      post: post
      gMarker: gMarker

    @markers.push marker
```

I suppose I could create a new map and attach all the markers to the new map, but this seems unnecessary because I may have many other overlays on the map

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to attach the `Map` object to another DOM element after the `Map` object has been created. As you can see in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=nl#Map) there is only a `getDiv()` method available on the `Map`, **not** a `setDiv()`.

I think you could hold on to the other objects like `Marker` and `MapOptions` to recreate the `Map`, but the `Map` object itself is useless without the corresponding DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global variable, mapOptions, where you can store the options of the map. Whenever some interaction is done with the map, you can update the mapOptions objects, and  save it to localstorage.

```
var mapOptions = {
   ...
};

localStorage.setItem("mapOptions", JSON.stringify(mapOptions));
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), localStorage.getItem("mapOptions"));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used this approach in my Vue app.  I stored the rendered map in my Vuex state and used this approach to "rebind" my map to the document.

Comment: @NathanAgersea Do you remember how you did that? This answer re-creates the map-object with the stored options. You instead stored the rendered map in vuex, but I do not see a way to rebind the div to that.

Comment: @JackLeEmmerdeur, yes, I used the ref attribute in my template and then used a watcher.  Does that give you enough to work through it?

Comment: @NatchanAgersea Sort of. I know how to use vuex and watchers. The part I was curious about was how to rebind the internal Maps-Object to a new div, as mwijnands points out that this is impossible. Thanks anyway but nevermind my question. In my app I won't leave the map-page ever and continously use the same Map-Object.